# Enable mailbox in exchange server for an existing user in active directory via HTTP API

Tags: exchange-server, windows-server, windows-server-2016, skype-for-business, exchange-server-2016

Is there any REST/SOAP API built in Exchange Server which give me to create mailbox for an existing user in active directory?
I know how to do it by Remote PowerShell, it is possible using cmdlet [Enable-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/enable-mailbox?view=exchange-ps).

Also, I need to enable users in Skype for Business Server. In PowerShell it's possible using cmdlet [Enable-CsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/enable-csuser?view=skype-ps).

I can't use Remote PowerShell for security reasons, that is why I need some HTTP API